# How to update City, post code in Review page after paypal express redirect in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, paypal

I am working on the one page checkout in Magento and selected the Paypal Express checkout. Now i faced problem with **Checkout with Paypal** default button that set for the user's that not want to fill there details in the form.

Now what happen, after redirect to the Review page `http://localhost/magento/index.php/paypal/express/review/`, I just get the address of the user not the city and Postcode that i have to display on the review form,

anyone please help me what i have to do to display the appropriate fields data into the form or how do i check if paypal returned or not the city and postcode on review page?